# Hide columns in ASPxGridView when value in ASPxSummaryItem is 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, devexpress

Here Is where I have my `gridview`:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="GridViewID" runat="server" DataSourceID="SourceMain" ClientInstanceName="Grid" SettingsPager-mode="ShowAllRecords" OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared">
 <Columns>
     <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="TrackOutDate" VisibleIndex="1" Visible="True"><PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="MM/dd/yyyy"></PropertiesTextEdit></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
     <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="LotID" VisibleIndex="2" Visible="True"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
     <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Qty_IN" VisibleIndex="11" Visible="True"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
     <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="HX" VisibleIndex="12" Visible="True"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
     <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="NA" VisibleIndex="13" Visible="True"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
 </Columns>
    <Settings ShowFooter="true" />
    <TotalSummary> 
    <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="Qty_IN" SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="{0}" Tag="1" ShowInColumn="Qty_IN"  />
    <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="HX" SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="{0}"/>
    <dx:ASPxSummaryItem FieldName="NA" SummaryType="Sum" DisplayFormat="{0}"/>
    </TotalSummary>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

And this is the code to fill that `gridview`:

```
protected void SourceMain_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    lote = getLot();
    device = getDevice();
    stage = getStage();
    location = getLocation();
    equipment = getEquipment();
    SD = Convert.ToDateTime(getStartDate());
    ED = Convert.ToDateTime(getEndtDate());

    MetricsPortal.DAL.ReportsDataClassesDataContext dataContext = new MetricsPortal.DAL.ReportsDataClassesDataContext();
    e.Result = (from items in dataContext.CalculateDailyYieldequipmentParam(lote,device,stage,location,equipment,SD,ED,Evaluation())
                orderby items.TrackOutDate ascending, items.GRANDTOTAL1 descending
                //where items.GRANDTOTAL1 > 0
                select items).Distinct();

}//source Main
```

Is it possible to remove or hide a column when the total summary of these columns is 0?

Ex: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkkHP.png)

In the column in yellow the value is 0, can I hide this column in this case? and when is not 0 just show the column?

Answer (score 1):

actually onselected event is more appropriate any way just  `GridView1.Columns[yourcolumnindex].Visible = false;` 
and column will disappear.

Comment: I use that below where I filled my gridview, but it doesn't work because cannot evaluate totalsummary, because it's not rendered yet, and if I tried to put on ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared method, still not working because the gridview doesn't have any data.

Comment: i guess you're using devexpress grid component. i'm not familiar much but i search devexpress support center and i find a couple of answers to matches your issue . basically HtmlRowCreated event used this type situation.

Comment: [link 1](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T197294/aspxgridview-onhtmldatacellprepared-e-visibleindex-value-always-2147483647)                         
[link 2](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T129714/aspxgridview-in-batch-editing-mode-javascript-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read)


: